# How to define a local variable correctly in lua and refer it to XML?

Tags: xml, lua

I'm trying to identify the public guild note as a local variable in lua and have the value of that variable referred in the XML file. Now I'm not sure if this is the correct code on how to do that.

```
local gngn()
_, _, _, _, _, _, gngn, _ = GetGuildRosterInfo("player");
end
```

If so, I want to embed this variable in the XML file

```
<FontString name="$parent_Text" inherits="GameFontNormal" 
text="&lt;22575&gt; ">
```

to be replaced with the dummy text <22575>

Answer (score 0):

You can define local variables in Lua in the following manner:

```
local var1, _, var3 = 1, 2, 3
```

The underscore _ is a special placeholder to dismiss a value. So, the 2 will be lost, but 1& 3 stored in the variables.

Get a player's public guild note:

```
local _, _, _, _, _, _, playerNote = GetGuildRosterInfo("player");
```

As for the XML file, you have 2 options:

1. create a new XML entry and write it to the XML file yourself

```

```
local newXmlEntry = '<FontString name="$parent_Text" inherits="GameFontNormal" text="'.. playerNote ..' ">'
```

2. replace the current entry of the XML file and then update the whole
   file

```

```
-- open file
local xmlFile = assert(io.open(xmlFilePath, "r"))
-- read and store all text
local xmlText = xmlFile:read("*a")
xmlFile:close()

-- replace all placeholders with playerNote text
string.gsub(xmlText, "&lt;22575&gt;", tostring(playerNote))

-- write updated xml file
xmlFile = assert(io.open(xmlFilePath, "w+"))
xmlFile:write(xmlText)
xmlFile:close()
```

Comment: Regarding method 1,how do I write it to the xml file?
Since that the original xml script was in a <frame> tag.

Regarding method 2, it didn't work.

Comment: That is completely up to you how you write / replace #1 in the XML file. I don't have the source of data you work on. And #2 was only supposed to work if you do the necessary modification and add the xmlFilePath to open the XML file on your disk

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making an addon for WoW. Assuming this, your question is not currently possible.

The Lua environment in WoW does not include the io library, so creating or editing the xml file is not an option. Additionally, XML attributes and Lua code embedded in an XML file can only access global variables (excepting of course any locals created in the embedded context).  Also, [`GetGuildRosterInfo`](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetGuildRosterInfo) requires an index, not a unit.

That said, what you *can* do is access `$parent_Text` from you Lua file and call `$parent_Text:SetText()` to update the string.

For example, if you are looking for your own note you could use this:

```
local playerName = UnitName("player")
for i = 1, GetNumGuildMembers() do
    local name, _, _, _, _, _, note = GetGuildRosterInfo(i)
    -- GetGuildRosterInfo provides the name of a player in the
    --  format "charName-serverName", we can use Ambiguate to
    --  get just the charName.

    if Ambiguate(name) == playerName then
        -- we found the player, so set the note

        -- "$parent" should be replaced with whatever the parent frames' name is
        $parent_Text:SetText(note)

        -- we've done what we wanted, so exit the loop
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting an error that says Unexpected symbol near '$' in the line of $parent_Text:SetText(note). And also I'm not sure where to go frorm here, since I this code was originally copied from another addon and I'm not that great on lua nor xml.

In the original code, the XML file contains the frame which has the text, in lua, I'm defining the guild not, I want to put the guild note value in the frame in the xml file. Seeing to what you said that I can't do that, I'm not sure how I can do that within the lua file.

Comment: So in XML files, "$parent" is used as a placholder string in a widget's name. When the XML file is read, "$parent" is replaced with the parent widgets name.For the sake of example lets say the parent is named "PlayerNoteFrame". In order to reference the text in lua you have to use the full name, which means replacing "$parent" with the actual parent name, which in this example would result in the font string having the name "PlayerNoteFrame_Text".